# Test the pass through authentication connection of a new website using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I need to test the pass through authentication connection of a new website using PowerShell.

The code that I have just creates the website.

```
New-WebApplication -Name DLTItemAnalysis -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationFolder\ApplicationFolder -ApplicationPool ApplicationPool
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site' and @id='1']/application[@path='/Application']/VirtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName=$ServUserName ;password= $ServUserPassword}
```

Is there a way to also test the user connection like the GUI has?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are asking for here.  for as documented:

***It is an authentication bridge*** and a new powerful way of cloud authentication while still keeping your passwords on-premise. It securely validates user passwords with on-premise Active Directory without the need of extra on-premise infrastructure like ADFS. Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Pass-through Authentication allows your users to sign in to both on-premises and cloud-based applications using the same passwords. This feature provides your users with a better experience - one less password to remember and reduces IT helpdesk costs because your users are less likely to forget how to sign in. When users sign in using Azure AD, this feature validates users' passwords directly against your on-premises Active Directory.

When a user types in his user name and password on office 365 portal https://portal.office.com, office 365 service encrypt this using public key and puts it in a queue for validation, one of lightweight agent makes an outbound call from your network to retrieve the user name and password and decrypts the password using organization’s private key and validate it against local AD. Local AD sends back the resulting success or failure and it goes back to Azure portal via an agent and the user is authenticated.

So, this is nothing more than a standard Windows Kerberos auth request being redirected. So, you are only require testing for normal Windows auth.

As noted above, PTA is a communications channel, not an auth type, like basic, integrated, Kerberos, Kerberos(required), etc. For a target to validate a specific auth type, the target has to be configured for it. There is not PTA auth type as noted above that you can configure on a target.

***Microsoft's PTA Video***
[User sign-in with Azure Active Directory Pass-through Authenticat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta)ion

> What is Azure Active Directory Pass-through Authentication? Azure
>   Active Directory (Azure AD) Pass-through Authentication allows your
>   users to sign in to both on-premises and cloud-based applications
>   using the same passwords. This feature provides your users a better
>   experience - one less password to remember, and reduces IT helpdesk
>   costs because your users are less likely to forget how to sign in.
>   When users sign in using Azure AD, this feature validates users'
>   passwords directly against your on-premises Active Directory

Comment: This is going to be used in non Azure environments. IIS version 10 and above on Server 2016 servers.

I am trying to automate a website that will be recreated in different customer environments on Windows 2016 servers

I want to make sure that the service user credentials that were used in the script that I am writing work. The GUI has the ability to run a test of the credentials, I wanted to see if that test can be replicated using PowerShell

Comment: Again, PTA is specifically designed to deal with easing auth scenarios to O365/Azure. There is little need for this auth type for on-prem since the PTA goal is to just pass native kerb to a target. That is all IIS is going to see. If you are trying to get eSSO on-prem, that is what KCD is for. Though on-prem ADFS can be used as well since the desktop browser can be configured to claims auth thru ADFS to the ADFS target that has an SPN configured transparently. So, again, you are only expecting a kerb success response.

Comment: The development team that created the application for this website. Put the PTA in its installation instructions. The reason is to verify that the credentials work and there isn't any issues before proceeding with the rest of the installation.

I am trying to implement the installation as efficiently as possible. Besides, I am still  curious to know if it is possible to run the test in PowerShell.